# jQuery get attribut of child with opacity 1

Tags: jquery, css

I am not good at jquery. I want to get class attribute of a child element of div whose **opacity** is **1**. Sample code is as below

```
<div class='parent'>
   <img class='child1' style='opacity:0;' />
   <img class='child2' style='opacity:0;' />
   <img class='child3' style='opacity:1;' />
   <img class='child4' style='opacity:0;' />
   <img class='child5' style='opacity:0;' />
   <img class='child6' style='opacity:0;' />
   <img class='child7' style='opacity:0;' />
</div>
```

What I tried:

```
1. $('.parent').find('img').css('opacity','1').attr('class');
```

but it did not worked.

```
2. $('.parent>img{opacity:1}').attr('class');
```

this also did not worked.

Can you please guide me how to get it done.

Comment: Do you realize you have spelt it wrong in your JavaScript? It should be "opacity"

Comment: Sorry my bad but I wrote it wrong in this question only. I have written it correctly in code.

Comment: @Purmou: to get class attribute value.

Comment: @A.K - please avoid "look at my answer" comments. They are considered noise and in any case are unnecessary; the OP will be alerted to your answer as soon as it is posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.parent img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('opacity') == 1;
}).attr('class');
```

This assumes, as you say, that there is only a single element with opacity 1. If there were more, this would return the class of only the first matching element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
var child = null;

$('.parent img').each(function() {
   if(parseInt($(this).css('opacity')) == 1) {
      child = $(this);
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Don't use this one. Use `.filter()` - My solution gives only one element as result (the first match) which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following syntax:

```
$('.parent').find("img^[style='opacity:1;']").attr('class')
```

## [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/YjzSB/)

Answer (score 1):

Here a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/ESaM2/) of what you are looking for... you need to use `.filter()` in jQuery

---

EDIT:

**Utkanos** did the same as mine, before me.

```
$('.parent img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('opacity') == 1;
}).attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing data in the class attribute and using inline styles, style with classes and store data in a custom attribute:

CSS - Children of the parent are normally invisible, but become opaque if they have the `visible` class

```
div.parent > img {
    opacity:0;
}

div.parent > img.visible {
    opacity:1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='parent'>
    <img data-field='child1' />
    <img data-field='child2' />
    <img data-field='child3' class="visible" />
    <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.parent > img.visible').attr('data-field');
//or
$('.parent > img.visible').data('field');
```